# shell script to display app version number

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the application version using the below command

```
#!/bin/sh
appVersion=$(ssh username@server find '/dir1/dir2/dir3' -type f  -name "file.json" -exec grep "version" {} \;| awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g')
echo $appVersion
```

Unfortunately am getting the below exception 
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't you need to doubly-escape the terminator of the `-exec` command `\\\;` ? (Once for `$()`) and once for the remote shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Run the below script, which will behave as expected.
When you run command over ssh, you should use **single quote** for the multiple commands

```
#!/bin/sh
appVersion=$(ssh username@server 'find '/dir1/dir2/dir3' -type f  -name "file.json" -exec grep "version" {} \;| awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g'')
echo $appVersion
```

[Refer this link for further details](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/)

Comment: Thanks but when i ran this iam getting an empty response,puting the complete script here.What went wrong here, please suggest

Comment: #!/bin/sh
declare -a server=(server)
jsonName=(file.json)
serverLen=${#server[@]}
for ((i=0; i<${serverLen}; i++))
do
appVersion=$(ssh user@$server 'find /home/user/sample -type f  -name "${jsonName[$i]}" -exec grep "version" {} \;' | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g')
echo "appversion is"  $appVersion
done

Comment: Result
appversion is

Comment: try to run the command `find ... ` alone in the target and then execute over ssh. By this way you could isolate the issue and solve it.

Comment: i understood the issue,when i hard coded the json value as "file.json" in the find  i got the version correctly, but when left to read from array empty result was obtained.
Not sure where it went wrong

Comment: i got the answer, the problem was double quotes should be included in the find command

Comment: share your working code which will help others to understand the issue better.

Comment: I used the below script 
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
serviceName=(server1 server2 )
jsonName=(file1.json file2.json )
serviceNameLen=${#serviceName[@]}
for ((i=0; i<=${serviceNameLen}; i++))
do
        declare -a appVersion=($(find /home/userName/sample -type f  -name "${jsonName[$i]}" -exec grep -i version {} \; | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g' )
        echo $appVersion
done
echo "array of 1" ${appVersion[0]} ${appVersion[1]}

Comment: and i was iterating thru for loop , the problem now is iam not getting the array element outside the for loop.
my plan is to take the first element of array mapped into html cell1,second element into html cell2 etc.

Comment: The values are getting stored in array inside the for loop , but not able to retrieve outsde the for loop where iam getting only 1 element
please help on this

Comment: declare the variable outside the loop and use it, Scope of your variable inside the loop only.

Comment: still no luck, i declared array variable outside the for loop, the problem is array is recogonizing only one element,please see the out put
bash +x pocversion_arun.sh
1.18.15
0.2.10
0.2.10
array of 1 0.2.10
here first three are the values which comes if i put the array varaible inside for loop
but the last output is the one which comes outside the for loop

Comment: declare -a appVersion

Comment: Puting the source code here

#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
serviceName=(server1 server2 )
jsonName=(file1.json file2.json )
serviceNameLen=${#serviceName[@]}
declare -a appVersion
for ((i=0; i<=${serviceNameLen}; i++))
do
        appVersion=($(find /home/userName/sample -type f  -name "${jsonName[$i]}" -exec grep -i version {} \; | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g' )
        echo $appVersion
done
echo "array of 1" ${appVersion[0]} ${appVersion[1]}